# UseDatabaseNullSemantics still generating NULL checks

Tags: sql, linq

I have this on my context object (constructor):

```
this.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
```

But even with this set, this query:

```
var query = (from i in _repo.Invoices
             join o in _repo.Orders on i.orderid equals o.orderid
             join o2 in _repo.Orders on o.linkedorderid equals o2.linkedorderid  into leftOrders
             from lo in leftOrders.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where invoiceIds.Contains(i.invoiceid)
             select new
             {
                i, lo
             }).ToList();
```

Returns this SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[invoiceid] AS [invoiceid], 
    [Extent1].[custid] AS [custid], 
    [Extent1].[orderid] AS [orderid], 
    [Extent1].[orderamount] AS [orderamount], 
    [Extent1].[invoiceamount] AS [invoiceamount], 
    [Extent1].[paidamount] AS [paidamount], 
    [Extent1].[paidstatus] AS [paidstatus], 
    [Extent1].[printdate] AS [printdate], 
    [Extent1].[updateddate] AS [updateddate]
    FROM   [dbo].[invoices] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[orders] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[orderid] = [Extent2].[orderid]
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[orders] AS [Extent3] ON ([Extent2].[linkedorderid] = [Extent3].[linkedorderid]) OR (([Extent2].[linkedorderid] IS NULL) AND ([Extent3].[linkedorderid] IS NULL))
    WHERE [Extent1].[invoiceid] IN (3098489, 3123185, 3156838)
```

It's not hard to see that I'm getting a System.OutOfException error since I have tons of orders with linkedorderid equals NULL.

If I remove `OR (([Extent2].[linkedorderid] IS NULL) AND ([Extent3].[linkedorderid] IS NULL))` query runs fine and returns all invoices that have or not children work orders...

Any idea how can I solve this ?

Comment: Does this join make sense? I think that either `o.linkedorderid` or `o2.linkedorderid` should be something like `orderId`. Now you join orders with themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work? If the posted query is correct when you remove the (or (is null and is null)) clause, then I think this will execute the same query. (This assumes there isn't a logic error in the joins, as suggested in other posts.)

```
var query = (from i in _repo.Invoices
    from o in _repo.Orders.Where(c => c.orderid == i.orderid)
    from o2 in _repo.Orders.Where(c => c.linkedorderid == o.linkedorderid).DefaultIfEmpty()                          
    where invoiceIds.Contains(i.invoiceid)
    select new
    {
       i, o2
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition you see inside the generated SQL has nothing in common with `UseDatabaseNullSemantics` and is needed to handle correctly `LEFT LOIN`s with **nullable** keys.

I think the problem you are experiencing is caused by a logical error in your query. IMO, the join condition

```
on o.linkedorderid equals o2.linkedorderid
```

should be

```
on o.linkedorderid equals o2.orderid
```

because normally the **FK** relates (joins) to the **PK**.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Ivan, but the logic is fine.

Comment: Really? So it's supposed to join the record to itself, can't believe that. But you know better, good luck.

Comment: @Catinodeh I also have a hard time believing the join passes a sanity check. Suppose all `linkedorderid` were unique (and not null). Then you'd just join two identical orders. If they aren't unique (ignoring the null issue) then you create Cartesian products for each value of `linkedorderid`, causing each invoice and each order to occur many times in the result set. I fail to see how that can be useful. Maybe you should explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @GertArnold Please take my apologies, I haven't noticed your first comment, otherwise I wouldn't have posted this answer.

Comment: No sweat :). I'm glad we both had the same doubts.